# Apache 2.2.21 upgrade from 2.2.8, what is the best way to do this on a production system?

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl

I have little experience in being a web application administrator however I am a software developer.  I inherited support for a legacy application that jkMount's a JBoss application server farm and the front end are two Apache 2.2.8 with OpenSSL servers preconfigured and running on Windows Server 2003.

The [recent publicized security flaw](https://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/apache-releases-version-2221-new-fix-range-header-flaw-091411) triggered a response from my manager that I need to upgrade the Apache servers to the most secure version, 2.2.21.

I believe I know what I need to do in theory but I have never personally installed or upgraded Apache before so I am a little nervous.  My plan was to:

- Backup the existing installation location completely
- Stop the Apache Servers
- Install to the same location via the MSI installer I downloaded
- Replace the installed contents of the `/conf/` directory with the backed up contents of the pre-configured `/conf/` directory (including SSL certs).
- Restart the servers and pray to God/Allah/Spaghetti Monster.

Do you see anything that I may be missing?  I imagine the only differences between 2.2.8 and 2.2.21 are just security updates and that configuration files should be interchangeable?

Comment: FYI, I updgraded Apache on my local test server following roughly these steps and it was a lot easier than I thought.  The uninstaller for the old version left all of my configurations and third party modules untouched.  I just installed the new version and everything is working fine, including SSL on test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you have it down fine, I was going to suggest testing it on another server first if you could, then I read your comment.

Comment: Thanks!  I feel more confident now.  I was hoping to get a quick and easy answer.  I will do this tonight, if all goes well I will award you the points.